# Android sharedPreferences not saving with commit/apply/clear

Tags: java, android, serialization, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the text contents of a `TextView` when my app closes, so I am trying to save that info in the `onDestroy` method, and then set them in the `onCreate` method.

I have written the following 2 functions to get rid of the boilerplate of getting and putting a value in the shared prefs:

```
fun MainActivity.putStringInPrefs(prefsFile: String, key: String, value: Any) =
    getSharedPreferences(prefsFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString(key, value.toString())
            .apply()

fun MainActivity.getStringFromPrefs(prefsFile: String, key: String, default: Any = "") : String =
    getSharedPreferences(prefsFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(key, default.toString())
```

When the app closes this is what gets called:

```
override fun onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy()
        log("OnDestroy!")
        putStringInPrefs(mainPrefsFile, "lastSelectedItemDescription", textViewItemDetailsTextView.text) }
```

`log` is just a wrapper around `Log.d("", "string")`

And in the `onCreate`  this gets called:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ; log("OnCreate!")
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Set up the item details text view
            textViewItemDetailsTextView.text = getStringFromPrefs(mainPrefsFile, "lastSelectedItemDescription", detailsText)
```

Problem is that whatever I do the preferences are not saved and the default value is always returned in `onCreate`. I have tried both apply and commit, with and without clear. No results. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: not a direct answer to your issue but you might consider using new Android KTX and it's shared preference "wrapper" (https://github.com/android/android-ktx)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly thank you! that seems useful but I am only starting to play with android so I want to get my hands dirty for a bit before abstracting it all away to get used to the way thing are. But still, thanks alot!

Comment: You should simplify you code by not using extension functions, but implement methods `putStringInPrefs ` and `getStringFromPrefs ` directly in you Activity. Also you can remove the prefsFile argument and replace it with a string constant, as you will always read and write you key from the same place and to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

`super.onDestroy()` should be the last line in your overridden method `onDestroy()`. You might experience unexpected behaviour on whatever code you execute after "destructive" code has been executed

Comment: Are you sure you asked for the same "prefsFile" ?

Comment: yes. The `mainPrefsFile` is actually a member of the `MainActivity`, it is initialized right at the start(outside of `onCreate`, a member of the class itself) `val mainPrefsFile: String = "main_prefs"`

Answer (score 1):

Save `Activity` state in `onDestroy()` is not good idea, because it is possible for the system to kill the process hosting your activity without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback. ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onstop)).

To save state you can use `onSaveInstanceState` / `onRestoreInstanceState` instead. See: [Saving and restoring activity state](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras)

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    outState?.putString(YOUR_TEXT, textView.text)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        textView.text = savedInstanceState.getString(YOUR_TEXT)
    }
}

companion object {
    val YOUR_TEXT = "your_text"
}
```